# Why does AbstractStringBuilder.append behave differently for MIN_VALUE?

Tags: java

Consider the following methods in `java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder`

---

**Long**

```
public AbstractStringBuilder append(long l) {
    if (l == Long.MIN_VALUE) {
        append("-9223372036854775808");
        return this;
    }
    int appendedLength = (l < 0) ? Long.stringSize(-l) + 1
                                 : Long.stringSize(l);
    int spaceNeeded = count + appendedLength;
    ensureCapacityInternal(spaceNeeded);
    Long.getChars(l, spaceNeeded, value);
    count = spaceNeeded;
    return this;
}
```

**Integer**

```
public AbstractStringBuilder append(int i) {
    if (i == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
        append("-2147483648");
        return this;
    }
    int appendedLength = (i < 0) ? Integer.stringSize(-i) + 1
                                 : Integer.stringSize(i);
    int spaceNeeded = count + appendedLength;
    ensureCapacityInternal(spaceNeeded);
    Integer.getChars(i, spaceNeeded, value);
    count = spaceNeeded;
    return this;
}
```

---

Why does `AbstractStringBuilder#append` use a different algorithm to append the `MIN_VALUE` ?

Comment: Do you mean why are both `MIN_VALUE`s special cased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Integer.stringSize` requires a non-negative argument. The code looks like this:

```
final static int [] sizeTable = { 9, 99, 999, 9999, 99999, 999999, 9999999,
                                  99999999, 999999999, Integer.MAX_VALUE };

// Requires positive x
static int stringSize(int x) {
    for (int i=0; ; i++)
        if (x <= sizeTable[i])
            return i+1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the `stringSize` algorithm estimates the number of chars needed from the absolute value of its input, except that `MIN_VALUE` has no absolute value representable: `-Integer.MIN_VALUE == Integer.MIN_VALUE`.